# Tricky problem with mutations arrays in Vuex, how to solve?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex

I have a little async actions, that take data (array of objects) from server and commit mutation with this data. Then, in my mutation I pushing data to store. 
My first attempt was ES6-ish:

```
state.data = [...state.data, ...payload];
```

Troubleshooting state with console I saw that new state is have 205 elements, how it should be. But, if I checking state directly from Vuex devtools - length 0.

Ok, maybe problem with destructuring or whatever.

```
state.data = payload;
```

Doesnt work too. So, my third attempt was a dumbest ever:

```
payload.forEach(x => x.state.data.push(x));
```

And... it worked. But, it took time, like a lot (only 205 elements, Carl!)
So, my question -> whats wrong with Vue/Vuex?

Comment: Whould be cool if you can reproduce your problems in https://codesandbox.io/s/vue for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Vue.set()` function.

In your mutation method do something like:

```
Vue.set(state, 'data', payload);
```

[Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)